# Exclude fields from acf front end page editor

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a form for editing a page using ACF like this:

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'   => $post_id,
    'post_title'    => false,
    'submit_value'  => 'Submit changes'
));
```

This gives me a form with all the fields from this post. I don't want all of them to be displayed in the form and so wanna exclude them. Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: try it please :-  unset($form['post_title']). here i assume that your array which you shows is assigned to $form

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the array you're seeing consists of arguments

Comment: i didn't understand what you want to say?

Answer (score 2):

There is no option for exclude fields but you can use "field_groups" to include fields.

for ex.
Check your field group URL. It looks like: ../wp-admin/post.php?post=21&action=edit

'21' is you field group.

So change your code to:

```
acf_form(array(
    'post_id'   => $post_id,
    'post_title'    => false,
    'field_groups' => array(21),
    'submit_value'  => 'Submit changes'
));
```

for more info http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/

Good luck!!!